# Remove set of elements in an char array

Tags: c#

I have a char array where I have to remove the elements from the same if I find the certain char.  For eg: "paragraphs" is assigned in an char array. I have given search keyword as 'g'. If it is found then I have to remodify the original char array as "raphs" by removing all elements including the found one.

char[] ch = "paragraphs"

search chr = 'g'

Desired result(if chr found):

char[] ch = "raphs"

### To explain bit clearer

I have to write a func. to find whether str(user input) contains all the char of the word "abcdef" in the same sequence as specify in the "abcdef". Return True if contains all the char in the same sequence or else false.

User Input: fgajbdcmdgeoplfqz
Output: true

User Input: asrbcyufde
Output: false

Comment: Why a char array? Would be much simpler keeping it as a string and using the methods which are designed for these situations.

Comment: What would you expect the return value to be if there is more than one character found? if, in your example above, the search chr was 'a'?

Comment: So your 'clarification' is giving a completely different input/output than your original question.

Comment: Given that you are now stating a completely different problem: what have you tried. Post your code and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ's [`SkipWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549075%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will skip elements until the `search` character is found.

An additionnal `Skip` is necessary to obtain `raphs` instead of `graphs`, and the `ToArray()` for the input string and result because you want to work with arrays.

```
char[] ch = "paragraphs".ToArray();
char search = 'g';
ch = ch.SkipWhile(c => c != search).Skip(1).ToArray(); // raphs
```

---

But honestly since your input is a `string`, I'd work with that:

```
string ch = "paragraphs";
char search = 'g';
ch = ch.Substring(ch.IndexOf(search) + 1);
```

and, if really necessary, convert it with `.ToArray()` afterwards.

---

And now to answer your 'clarification' (which is pretty much an other question by the way).

There are probably better ways to do it, but here's something that will accomplish what you want in O(n)

```
private bool ContainsInSequence(string input, string substring)
{
    int substringIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == substring[substringIndex])
        {
            substringIndex++;
            if (substringIndex == substring.Length)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Basically, you go through the input string in order, and each time you encounter the current letter from your substring you move to the next one.

When you reach the end of the substring, you know the input string contained all your substring, so you return `true`.

If we're not at the end after going through all the input this means there was a letter either out of order or missing, so we return `false`.

```
ContainsInSequence("fgajbdcmdgeoplfqz", "abcdef"); // true
ContainsInSequence("asrbcyufde ", "abcdef"); // false
ContainsInSequence("abcdfe", "abcdef"); // false
```

Comment: Yay finally something that does what was asked (after your `ToArray()` edit), albeit not the most efficient solution possible.

Comment: For goodness sake, @Alex, why not post the most efficient solution possible yourself?!?!?

Comment: @RufusL I had no intention on posting an answer until such a time as the OP had expanded his question to show that he had actually *tried* to solve it, but in the mean time a flood of answers were posted, that did not actually answer the question and that I felt compelled to comment on.

Comment: @Alex, ah I see, just curious since you have been very vocal in the comments! But I agree, the question is incomplete and doesn't show any *real* code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        char[] ch = "paragraphs".ToCharArray();
        int index = Array.IndexOf(ch, 'g');
        char[] result = new string(ch).Substring(index+1).ToCharArray();
```

Comment: An `array of char` (his input) is not a `List<char>`. Also, his input is not a `string`. You are not answering the question.

Comment: Okay, I will modify it.

Comment: That will work. How about for the last line something more efficient like `if (index >= 0 && ch.Length - (index + 1) > 0) { var result = new char[ch.Length - (index + 1)]; Array.Copy(ch, index + 1, 0, result.Length); return result; } else return new char[0];` Since there is no need to allocate multiple strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version without using Linq:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Please provide a list of characters");
    string Charactersinput  = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please provide the search character");
    char Searchinput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    Console.WriteLine("");

    List<char> ListOfCharacters = new List<char>();
    //fill the list of characters with the characters from the string
    // Or empty it, if th esearch charcter is found

    for (int i = 0; i < Charactersinput .Length;  i++)
    {
        if (Searchinput == Charactersinput[i])
        {
            ListOfCharacters.Clear();
        }
        else
        ListOfCharacters.Add(Charactersinput [i]);

    }

    //get your string back together
    string Result = String.Concat(ListOfCharacters);


    Console.WriteLine("Here's a list of all characters after processing: {0}", Result);
    Console.ReadLine();



}
```

Comment: @Alex What do you think?

Comment: This would now print "raphs" as an output if an input of "paragraphs" were given and a search character of 'g'. Thus this is an improvement over your previously posted answer (i.e. it does the right thing). It still does not do exactly what was asked in the question though, since it does not use a `char` array for its input and output.

Comment: So he needs to use the same one for input and output?

Comment: What does it say in the question?  input: `char[] ch = "paragraphs";`, `char search_char = 'g';`  expected output: `char[] result;` with a value of `{'r', 'a', 'p', 'h', 's'}`. So your example should match these inputs and outputs. Try to write a method with this signature `public static char[] FilterCharArray(char[] input, char search_char)`, and write some code that performs the operation and returns the expected output. Then you will have answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your "clarification" question, which is very different from the original question:

> I have to write a func. to find whether str(user input) contains all
>   the char of the word "abcdef" in the same sequence as specify in the
>   "abcdef". Return `true` if contains all the char in the same sequence or
>   else `false`.
>
> Input: fgajbdcmdgeoplfqz Output: true 
>   Input: asrbcyufde Output: false

The following function takes in two strings, a source string to search and a string containing the sequence of characters to match. It then searches through the source string, looking for each character (starting at the found position of the previous character). If any character is not found, it returns false. Otherwise it returns true:

```
public static bool ContainsAllCharactersInSameSequence(string sourceString, 
    string characterSequence)
{
    // Short-circuit argument check
    if (sourceString == null) return characterSequence == null;
    if (characterSequence == null) return false;
    if (characterSequence.Length > sourceString.Length) return false;
    if (sourceString == characterSequence) return true;

    int startIndex = 0;

    foreach (char character in characterSequence)
    {
        int charIndex = sourceString.IndexOf(character, startIndex);
        if (charIndex == -1) return false;
        startIndex = charIndex + 1;
    }

    return true;
}
```